# Не удается обновить данные в бд из DataTable

Tags: база-данных, visual-basic

Добрый день. Заполняю datatablе значениями из базы. datatablе заполняю значениями из 2-х таблиц (использую объединенный запрос). 
Datatable в дальнейшем меняется, и эти изменения не получается внести в базу. Ошибки в процессе работы программы не возникает, просто бд не обновляется. Скажите пожалуйста в чем проблема. 
Заполнение datatable данными

```
sqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source = *; User id = *; Password = *; database=* ;Integrated Security = False;")
sqlConnection.Open()
commandStrEmployee = "SEL ECT e.id_correspondent, e.surname, d.title,d.id_duty fr om Employee e inner join Duty d on e.id_duty=d.id_duty"
adapterEmployee = New SqlDataAdapter(commandStrEmployee, sqlConnection)
adapterEmployee.Fill(dtEmployee)
```

Внесение данных в datatable

```
Dim a As DataRow = Form1.dtEmployee.Rows(i)
a.BeginEdit()
a("id_duty") = Form1.dt_duty.Rows(b)("id_duty")
a("title") = Form1.dt_duty.Rows(b)("title")
a.EndEdit()
a.AcceptChanges()
```

Обновление бд

```
Form1.adapterEmployee.Update(Form1.dtEmployee)
```

Почему-то последняя строчка не срабатывает.

Comment: Отформатируйте код

Answer (score 1):

Делал похожую программу на C# с занесением в БД из textbox. Код похож на VB, думаю поможет. Тут занясятся в БД 2 поля discipline и publishing.

> string discipline =
> Convert.ToString(comboBox1.Text);
>                 string publishing = Convert.ToString(textBox6.Text);
>
> ```
>             cls.Conn.Open();
>             SqlCommand iCommand = cls.Conn.CreateCommand();
>             iCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + "Books (Дисциплины,
> ```
>
> Издательство) " +
>                       "VALUES (@discipline, @publishing)";
>
> ```
>             iCommand.Parameters.Add("@discipline",
> ```
>
> SqlDbType.NChar, 100);
>                 iCommand.Parameters["@discipline"].Value
> = discipline;
>
> ```
>             iCommand.Parameters.Add("@publishing",
> ```
>
> SqlDbType.NChar, 30);
>                 iCommand.Parameters["@publishing"].Value
> = publishing;

В данном случае cls - это главный класс приложения, а Conn - переменная подключения к базе данных. Они описаны так:

> static public SqlConnection Conn;

Хотя последний пункт можешь опустить.
В твоём случае проще будет сделать занесение полей БД в переменную и занести их в БД отдельным потоком, как показано у меня.